# Selenium, PHPUnit - click on link using xpath

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, click, phpunit

I want to click on link using XPath, but I cant find any solution.
This is the xpath

```
//td[text()='".$Variable."']/../td/div/a"
```

The xpath is working, it highlights correct element. But I'm unable to click on it.
The whole syntax is here

```
$this->click("xpath=//td[text()='".$Variable."']/../td/div/a");
```

And this is the error message I get, when I try to run the test.

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I read some articles, but most of them are using java. I want this in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, here is one more example. 
probably even more suitable for you:

```
<?php
class GitHubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->webDriver->close();
    }

    public function testSearch()
    {
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        // find search field by its id
        $search = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('js-command-bar-field'));
        $search->click();

        $webElement = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@property="abracadabra"]'));
    }    
}
?>
```

so you can see how is element located using xPath.
This example is taken from [Working with PHPUnit and Selenium Webdriver](http://codeception.com/11-12-2013/working-with-phpunit-and-selenium-webdriver.html). I think you can find it helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with  [Facebook php-WebDriver library](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) .

This one solution worked fine for me:

```
$loginButtonCSS="#loginbutton";

$submitButton=driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector(loginButtonCSS));
$submitButton->click();
```

Alternative using xPath:

```
// NOTE: try to omit symbols  '  in your xPath
$elementXpath= "xpath=//td[text()=".$Variable."]/../td/div/a"; 
$webElement= driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($elementXpath));
$webElement->click();
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But there is also a problem. It might be because I do not have installed facebook php-webdriver properly.
This is the error message now when I want to run this test.
`InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression xpath=//td[text()=XXX180881]/../td/d
e following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired`

Comment: Wait, if I understand well, I have to rewrite everything in my code according to facebook php-webdriver expressions?

Comment: firstly, try to check whether you've figured out xPath of the element properly:   i.e.  check this xPath in fireBug:  http://gyazo.com/61504eb631451c457112be347438f123   ;  secondly, check whether you've included all necessary libs properly and you're able to perform webDriver methods calls

Answer (score 0):

if you use the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase

store the expression in a variable

```
$xpath="//input[@value='text']";
$this->byXPath($xpath)->click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're not extending the correct class. Seems that you're trying to use selenium rc. You should extend **PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase** if you want to use:

```
$this->click("//someXpath");
```

If you're using php-webdriver, you'll have to extend **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** and also include the php facebook webdriver (or any other php-webdriver library you're using). Keep in mind that the selenium RC tests will not work on webdriver and vice-versa. As you see, they have different ways of identifying and interacting with elements and with the browser itself. More info regarding selenium & phpunit, [Here](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html).